# Show that $G$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

I have to show that $$G=\{2n \mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ under addition is a group. I know for something to be a group it must satisfy $4$ things: identity, inverse, associativity and closure. I'm confused with what I'm supposed to do since I just have one element, $2n$, and I don't know what I'm suppose to do with the 'addition' part.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have infinitely many elements: ..., -4, -2, 0, 2, ...

Comment: I know that. But how do I show that for like identity if a*e=a=e*a.

Answer (score 1):

The group operation is "ordinary addition", so for $a, b \in G$, $ab = a + b$. What you need to show is:

- $0$ is even i.e., it's a member of $G$. ($0$ will be $e$, the unit of the group, and for $a \in G$,  $ae = a + 0$.)
- If $n$ is even, then $-n$ is even.
- Associativity you get "for free", because ordinary addition is associative.
- If $n, m$ are even, then $n+m$ is even.

Comment: So why am I trying to show these things?

Comment: Um, so that you can show that $G$ forms a group with the group operation being ordinary addition. You do realize that $G$ is the set of even integers, yes?

Comment: what would the difference be if it was multiplication?

Comment: It wouldn't be a group: it the operation were to be ordinary multiplication, the unit would have to be $1$, so inverses wouldn't exist – $1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \dots, 58/19, \dots$ aren't integers. The set of even integers is still "closed under multiplication", but the structure $(G, *)$ is only a *monoid* (set with an associative binary operation), not a group.

Comment: Ahhh. So for identity could I write a*e=a=e*a & a*e=a+e=a, e=0. Or do I have to incorporate the 2n?

Comment: I would write $a + 0 = 0 + a = a$ for the identity case. For the others, I'd show the elements as multiples of $2$ explicitly. E.g. "given $a = 2 n, -a = - (2 n) = 2 (-n) \in G$ because $-n \in \mathbb{Z}$.